# How to calculate distance between two PointField?

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango, django-1.9

I use Postgis with Django to store geographic points. I have a model like the following:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Event(models.Model)
    position = models.PointField()
```

I have two events(ev1, ev2). Here is the position value of each:

```
SRID=4326;POINT (-73.6335140000000052 45.5472019999999986)
SRID=4326;POINT (-73.6267909999999972 45.5459189999999978)
```

My goal is to get distance in meters between those two points. If i do:

```
ev1.position.distance(ev2.position)
```

I get `0.006844327432269004`

How can I convert this value in meters?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use the Geography type, the distance result will be in meters. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.GeometryField.geography

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to make it work, but only through a queryset. Here I wanted to get the distance between Event 3 and all other Events:

```
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance

p2 = Event.objects.get(id=3).position
for event in Event.objects.all().exclude(id=3).annotate(distance=Distance('position', p2)):
    print('{0} - {1}'.format(event.id, event.distance.m))
```

"position" is the name of the PointField

Answer (score 3):

pnt.distance(pnt2) * 100

will give you distance in km.Change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the class Distance, the database function Distance is used to perform the annotation:

```
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
```

Answer (score -2):

according to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/measure/#example

if you have:

```
in_meters = ev1.position.distance(ev2.position).m
```

you will get results in meters

Comment: The distance function returns only a float. I get this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'm'